# Choose school location to minimize daily path of students to school

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been trying to do this task for some time now and I can't seem to even get started. I don't want a solution but some kind of a hint.

> The distance from town $A$ to town $B$ is $3$ kilometers. Town $A$ has $100$ students, town $B$ has $50$ students. At what distance from $A$ should a school be built such that the length of the path students make every day is minimal.

The task is not homework, but I will tag it as such, to avoid well known lectures...

Comment: The length of which paths of the students should be minimal? Minimize the average distance or maximum distance?

Comment: @Cristi Then it's a good idea to wait for intuition to tell you a second thing, because the first one was totally wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask for a hint. The main idea in problems like these is to write down something that you can minimize. In this one, you've been told, although a bit vaguely. I think that what it's asking for is to minimize the total "work" of all the students (i.e., the number of student-kilometers travelled). So suppose you locate the school $x$ kilometers from $A$. A few questions to get you started:

1. How far will the school be from $B$?
2. How many km will one student from $A$ travel in one day?
3. How many km will ALL students from $A$ travel in one day?
4. Same questions for students from $B$.
5. What's the *total* travel done by all students? Your answer should involve the number $x$; call the answer $T(x)$.

Now see whether there's an obvious value of $x$ that makes $T(x)$ as small as possible. Note that you should only look for values of $x$ between $0$ and $3$, because it'd be crazy to locate the school anywhere outside of the line from $A$ to $B$.